# Is there any tutorials on Grafana Bubble Chart Panel?

Tags: visualization, grafana, bubble-chart, grafana-templating, grafana-alerts

I've tried following the example given in the documentation but nothing appears for the Grafana Bubble Chart Plugin

```
SELECT
UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date) as time_sec,
amt as value,
CONCAT(server, ',', org) as metric
FROM trade
WHERE $__timeFilter(date)
ORDER BY date ASC
```

This is a screenshot of what I'm working on. 
[Image of my bubble chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y63qd.png)

I'm not too sure on the "$tag_dc,$tag_host" in the documentation too. I'm new to Grafana. 
Any help or **examples that are working or tutorials** are appreciated.